# Java: Jar Byte Array to Instantiated Object

Tags: java, jar, classloader, inputstream

I have an byte array of a jar file and I want to instantiate an object defined by a class contained in the jar.  How to I do this?  Right now I am stuck at

```
InputStream inputStream = App.class.getResourceAsStream("/example.jar");
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

I think I will need 2 things, a zip file reader and a class loader.  Does that sound like the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) with the resource path you already have and instantiate the class. You dont have to read the bytes yourself

```
// Create URLClassLoader 
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file://pathToJar/example.jar")});
Class<?> lookupClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("com.somePackage.ClassName");
Object inst = lookupClass.newInstance();
```